# Can I create a Firebase account from code in my app

Tags: android, ios, windows

From a Windows, Android or IOS application, I would like to create a new Firebase account\project when the user installs the app.

Is that possible?

Comment: its not posible read the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52119532/9909365

Answer (score 0):

**No, it's not possible**

In order to create and add a project on firebase you need to upload your **package name** and

**SHA-1**(optional but still required for authenticating your client)

After that a JSON file will be generated and you have to put that file in your projects App folder and configure your Gradle files

so you can see now.
You cannot do this process on installing of app